# Formatting character in deltalake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

`columnName (FORMAT'99999999.999') (CHAR(12))`

How can I format this in deltalake , I searched for to_char method but there is no such method .

Can anyone help me please !

Answer (score 0):

I think can use

cast(format_string(columnName,'99999999.999') as CHAR(12))